# C++ - unordered_map on loop - execution of hash operator()

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Suppose i have for example, a `std::unordered_map<K,std::set<int>> table`. In the loop:

```
for(auto it = table[k].begin(); it != table[k].end(); ++it){}
```

will the hash operator() of K be called on every iteration? The compiler is `g++` with the flags: `-m64 -g -std=c++11 -O3`

Comment: It is definitely possible: strongly depends on compiler, optimization options, and context.

Comment: Depends on the compiler optimizations. If k is `constexpr`, compiler would definitely optimize. If it is a local stack variable and the compiler can see it is not modified in the loop, even then compiler will optimize.

Comment: Adding only one line `const auto &whatever = table[k];` will make this problem disappear and your code more readable at the same time, why to ask "is it ok to write bad code?"

Answer (score 5):

Unless the compiler can prove that k is not modified by anything happening in the loop, yes, it will be called each time around. For that matter, it'll be doing the table lookup every iteration too. (It's fairly likely that the compiler will reuse the hash but do separate lookups anyway.) The Standard doesn't allow implementations to just remove an operation like that, but it does allow them to make any optimizations they like which don't have any visible effects (the "as-if" rule).

The cleaner and more efficient way to write the loop would be:

```
for(int val : table[k]){}
```

That only needs to do one table lookup.

Comment: I think auto& is better here

Comment: @Yakk I thought about it, but (a) `auto` has one more character than `int`, and (b) you don't want to be implying that you're gonna mutate its keys. `auto const&` I'd maybe go for, though.